# @BeforeSuite and @Guice timing issue

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, testng, guice

I'm testing a ftp client library which internally uses `@Inject`. And I have a problem related to a timing issue.

```
public class FakeFtpServerTest {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void startFtpServer() {} // not invoked before injection

    @AfterSuite
    public void stopFtpServer() {}
}

public class MyFtpClientModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }
}

@Guice(modules={MyFtpClientModule.class})
public class MyFtpClientTest {

    @Inject
    @InjectMe
    private MyFtpClient client;
}
```

The problem is that the injection is invoked when `TestNG` creating an instance of `MyFtpClientTest` which means the time before `@BeforeSuite` is invoked.
And the module which binds and provides some ftp client which should be already connected to the fake ftp server fails.

How can I solve this problem? Is there any technique to solve this?

Comment: you could try annotating startFtpServer as `@PostConstruct`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like this. Instead of using `@Guice`, I programatically inject field on `@BeforeMethod`.

```java
public class MyFtpClientTest {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void startFtpServer() {} // not invoked before injection

    @AfterSuite
    public void stopFtpServer() {}

    @BeforeMethod
    public void injectFtpClient() {
        client = Guice.createInjector(this).getInstance(FileBack.class);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void ejectFtpClient() {
        client = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }

    @Inject
    private MyFtpClient client;
}
```